# How do you create mapping of multiple properties in the source to a List object in the destination?

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's say I have the following objects:

**Source:**

```
public class Scores()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal ScoreA { get; set; }
    public decimal ScoreB { get; set; }
    public decimal ScoreC { get; set; }
}
```

**Destination:**

```
public class ScoresDto()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Score> ScoreDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Score()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I understand how I can map straight 1 to 1 property mapping like this:

```
public AutomapperProfiles()
{
    CreateMap<Scores, ScoresDto>()
          .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
          .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Name))
}
```

However, how would I map as part of the above mapping ScoreA, ScoreB and ScoreC into individual new Score objects, where 'Name' is the name of the property and Value is the decimal value, and then have those scores make up the ScoreDetails list on ScoresDto?

Comment: Any library should make it easier to write code. If it turns out the opposite - the code becomes larger and more complex, then you should abandon the library. IMHO. I would write mapping without AutoMapper for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) to do the job;

```
public class ScoreDetailsResolver : IValueResolver<Scores, ScoresDto, IList<Score>>
{
    public IList<Score> Resolve(Scores source, ScoresDto destination, IList<Score> member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = destination ?? new ScoresDto();
        destination.ScoreDetails = destination.ScoreDetails ?? new List<Score>();
        destination.ScoreDetails.Add(new Score { Name = source.Name, Value = source.ScoreA });
        destination.ScoreDetails.Add(new Score { Name = source.Name, Value = source.ScoreB });
        destination.ScoreDetails.Add(new Score { Name = source.Name, Value = source.ScoreC });
        return destination.ScoreDetails;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
CreateMap<Scores, ScoresDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ScoreDetails, o => o.MapFrom<ScoreDetailsResolver>());
```

No need to map other properties as they will be mapped automatically.